# Where() method in Pandas with other a Pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

I am experimenting with the where() method in pandas.  I run the simple example in the documentation page with other being a pd.Series and I got NaNs which I can not explain:

The example dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
```

The where() clause is:

```
m = df % 3 == 0
n = pd.Series([100, 200])
df.where(m, n, axis = 1)
```

The method returns the following dataframe:

```
    A   B
0   0.0 NaN
1   NaN 3.0
2   NaN NaN
3   6.0 NaN
4   NaN 9.0
```

I was expecting to see 100 in A and 200 in B instead of NaNs.

Could you explain the NaNs?  Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Series, n, does not have the appropriate labels:

```
n
Out: 
0    100
1    200
dtype: int64
```

If you use this as the `other` parameter, it will use this Series only when the index is the same (on columns named 0 and 1). If it cannot find them, it will display NaN's. However, if you change the labels:

```
n.index = ['A', 'B']

n
Out: 
A    100
B    200
dtype: int64
```

Now it will work as you expect:

```
df.where(m, n, axis = 1)
Out: 
     A    B
0    0  200
1  100    3
2  100  200
3    6  200
4  100    9
```